# Problem with Post json data on flask server

Tags: android-studio, flask

i'm setting up a flask server and i would like to do HTTP POST request with a json content-type from android application.

for my purpose i only need to get json data from different client.
one of these client is an android application and it basically do an http post in the server.

the code of android post request is :

```
public void SendHttp(View view){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            final String lte_url="http://192.168.1.8:5000/data_center/lte";
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();

            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI uri = new URI("http://192.168.1.8:5000/data_center/lte");
                httpPost.addHeader(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
                httpPost.setURI(uri);
                JSONObject send_ = json_lte;
                txtSend.setText(""+send_.toString(2));
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("{"+
                        "\"date\":"+"\""+send_.getString("Date")+","+
                        "\"Ping\":"+send_.getString("Ping")+","+
                        "\"Download\":"+send_.getString("Download")+","+
                        "\"Upload\":"+send_.getString("Upload")+","+
                        "\"Latitude\":"+send_.getString("Latitude")+","+
                        "\"Longitude\":"+send_.getString("Longitude")+","+
                        "\"Type\":"+send_.getString("Type")+","+
                        "\"RsRq\":"+send_.getString("RsRq")+","+
                        "\"RsRp\":"+send_.getString("RsRp")+","+
                        "\"SINR\":"+send_.getString("SINR")+","+
                        "\"Bandwidth\":"+send_.getString("Bandwidth")+
                        "}");
                txtSend.setText(entity.toString());
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } catch (some Exeption...)}
        }
    }).start();
```

the only output of the flask server is it

- Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  192.168.1.237 - - [23/Jul/2019 22:47:58] "POST /data_center/lte HTTP/1.1" 201 -

the code about the server is :

```py
@app.route('/data_center/lte',methods=['POST'])
def post_LTE_data():
            try:
                data = request.get_json(force=True)

                packet = {
                          'date': data['Date'],
                          'ping': data['Ping'],
                          'download': data['Download'],
                          'upload': data['Upload'],
                          'latitude': data['Latitude'],
                          'longitude': data['Longitude'],
                          'type': data['Type'],
                          'RsRq': data['RsRq'],
                          'RsRp': data['RsRp'],
                          'SINR': data['SINR'],
                          'bandwidth': data['Bandwidth']
                          }

                lte.append(packet)
                return f"OK", 200
            except Exception or JsonError as exc:
                print(str(exc))

                return "some problem"+str(exc), 201
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to configure your logging module. You can replace the Python code `print(str(exc))` with `app.logger.error(str(exc))` to see if it produces some output. You can click [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/#basic-configuration) to find some useful code.

By the way, you can take a look at the content received by your Android client because it should receive the response `"some problem"+str(exc)`.

I do not know much about Android code, but it seems that you are dealing with a wrong JSON string. The right format is as below:

```
{
 "foo":"bar",
 "good":"bad"
}
```

In your Android code, you might have to replace

```
"\"date\":"+"\""+send_.getString("Date")+","
```

to

```
"\"date\":"+"\""+send_.getString("Date")+"\","
```

The above rule should be applied to all lines in the JSON string. Be careful about the symbol `""`, and you have to make sure that the data during POST is a valid JSON string. Also, I suggest you use another way like utilizing some libraries to build JSON strings to avoid typos.

Comment: i replace print(str(exc)) but the problem persist, maybe the error is on the json format

Comment: @colo I would say that there is an exception thrown from your Python program, so the response HTTP code is 201. In order to find the error, you have to have some methods to get the error information, for example, print the error information to your standard output, or save the error information to a file, or take a look at your Android program about the response. Replacing the code `print(str(exc))` is just a possible way to display the error message.

Comment: yeah but the error shows nothing exept an error in this line : data = request.get_json(force=True) 
but i don't know how to solve the problem

Comment: @colo Please see the updated answer. You have to display your request JSON string so that you can figure out what is going on.

Comment: yes it is the problem ! now all works fine thanks a lot !